# MouseLeftButtonUp Alternative - Windows Mobile

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile, touch

Is there any other sensible way where I can fire a touch event on a Windows Mobile App?

I have a Hangman game. I have a bunch of images which are the alphabet.

I've put all of the images inside a Scroll Viewer so the user can scroll through the list.

As a precaution, I've set the click event to MouseLeftButtonUp because if I set it to "Down", it will trigger the image code when really, the user just wanted to scroll.

However, even with MouseLeftButtonUp, I've still got the same problem. When I test it, it scrolls but if the finger is still on the same image and if I release my finger, it'll fire off the code behind that image...

How can I overcome this problem? I hope my situation makes clear sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use touch events rather than mouse events since Windows mobiles devices are designed for touch rather than mouse clicking.

Comment: Can you please point me in a direction where I can learn how to implement a simple Touch Event. Not Multi Gesture.... A simply one finger Touch.

Comment: I haven't really gotten the chance to work with touch events on silverlight, but a quick google search got me this. http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/tip-day-processing-touch-input  might be some help to you.